# Access to full FaceTime and Continuity-enabled phone call log (call history) on a Mac

Tags: macos, facetime, continuity, history

The **Mac's FaceTime application**, as of macOS Sierra, presents a **very simplified call log** (call history) in its main window:

- For any given contact,

  - only a (time-stamped) SINGLE entry for the MOST RECENT conversation is shown,
  - WITHOUT indicator as to whether the call was INCOMING or OUTGOING.

    - Only missed calls (printed in red) imply the call direction (they're by definition incoming).
  - WITHOUT information about the DURATION of the (most recent) call.

With phone calling via Continuity enabled, iPhone-mediated calls are shown in the same fashion.

**Contrast this with the iOS 10 Phone app, which shows a full call log.**

**Is there a way to gain access to the full call log *on a Mac*,** providing all the information that the iOS Phone app exposes?

Note: Ideally, there'd be a way to access the full call log from within the FaceTime application (I don't think there is), but I'm open to any Mac-based solution (physically accessing the iPhone that mediates the phone calls is *not* an option).

Comment: When you say "gain access to the full call log," do you mean cause it to appear in FaceTime, or just be able to access it somehow?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I don't understand why it doesn't show me all the calls that have been made via FaceTime with timestamps.

Comment: @dstepan: No, I still don't know how to do it. My sense is that Apple thinks of FaceTime's behavior in this respect as a helpful simplification, but I personally do not consider it that.